# Parsing long string and multiple rows PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel

Hi I'm trying to get all my input values from this long string:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxT3b.png

Here is the long string in text from the image above:

```
_method=PUT&_token=4z8XepvtT7TELlLeXsg5msGNnLNGR2NIbtfUKFNq&order_name=orderApi&status=&id_client=0&difficulty=&hideHours=0&hour31=2&hour_salaries31=3&id_task=6&id_ordertask=31&hour32=4&hour_salaries32=5&id_task=1&id_ordertask=32&hour%5B%5D=22&hour_salary%5B%5D=10&id_task%5B%5D=2&id_ordertask%5B%5D=&hour%5B%5D=33&hour_salary%5B%5D=2&id_task%5B%5D=2&id_ordertask%5B%5D=&id=251
```

Notice that hour%5B%5D is an array (which looks like this: hour[]) and that you can see it twice in that long string. You can see 
hour%5B%5D=22 and hour%5B%5D=33. I have also underline this with a red color in the image above.

I know how I can get the value of hour_salaries32. I can do that by doing this:

```
parse_str(Input::get('allInput'));

die($hour_salaries32);
```

Which give me the following output:

```
5
```

But I would gladly like to get all the values of the input names. Here you can see my input names:

```
order_name
status
id_client
difficulty
hideHours

hour31
hour_salaries31
id_task
id_ordertask

hour32
hour_salaries32
id_task
id_ordertask

hour%5B%5D
hour_salary%5B%5D
id_task%5B%5D
id_ordertask%5B%5D

hour%5B%5D
hour_salary%5B%5D
id_task%5B%5D
id_ordertask%5B%5D

id
```

I think I need a for loop for this, but I really don't know how to do this. Can someone help me, please? Gladly I'm waiting for your response. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: `print_r(Input::get('hour'))` - you will get an array,    
also you may use Input::all() to get all values

Comment: print_r(Input::get('hour')) gives me the value 1. I think that means the value true. And I have already tried Input::all(), but that gives me the value: link: http://i.imgur.com/wCSLkpX.png  But then I still don't know how to get the values of the input names. I don't want to have: _method=PUT&_token=4z8XepvtT7TELlLeXsg5msGNnLNGR2NIbtfUKFNq